# Preventing lazy loading in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to prevent lazy loading on one collection only? Assume that we have object A, that has two collections (for example @OneToMany) inside. Both of them are LAZY. I want to do something like evict on the second collection but still have the possibility to fetch data for the second, so evicting whole parent object is not the solution for me.

Comment: Some ugly solution came into my mind - set there a null value. But I would rather to prevent lazy fetching and have lazy initialization exception in case someone would want to initialize it. But i don't think such partial evicting is possible, isn't it?

Comment: what do you expect to happen when the lazy collection wich should not initialize is accessed? It sounds weird to want lazyloading on one collection and not the other. Can you share a use case for this?

Comment: It is hard to explain. It is a consequence of the design in the application that is not easy to change now. Because object is used in the hibernate session and the code is changed by many developers I want to be sure that they don't fetch the collection which would cause some difficult to analyse errors - so I would rather to be sure that null pointer exception will be thrown or some other exception. As I said it's hard to explain all the reasons. I know we could use some middle layer or DTO, but in this case it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am assuming that setting null value isn't such a bad solution. It means - "I don't want to have anything in this collection". But if someone know more about potential possibility to block lazy on only one proxy/ collection would be nice to have this information here.

Greetings.